# Description of all morphism of $f: \Bbb A^1_k\to E$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> let $\lambda\in k-\{ 0,1 \}$and consider the affine curve $V( Y^2-X(X-1)(X-\lambda)\subset \Bbb A^2_k )$,give a description of all morphisms $f: \Bbb A^1_k\to E$

i am stack after $\lambda_1\to Y^2-X(X-1)(X-\lambda_1) $,

$\lambda_2\to Y^2-X(X-1)(X-\lambda_2) $

$\lambda_1+\lambda_2\to 2Y^2-X(X-1)(X-\lambda_1-\lambda_2) $

and i have no idea what to do next. And i don't know whether i am correct or not.Can anyone help me?

Comment: No!  $\lambda$ is fixed for your $E:=V(Y^2=X(X-1)(X-\lambda))\subset\mathbb{A}^2$.

Comment: @ user10354138 i am not very understand , can you give me more details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving a morphism $f:\mathbb A^1\to E$ is equivalent to giving a homomorphism of coordinate algebras in inverse direction $f^\sharp:k[X,Y]/(Y^2-X(X-1)(X-\lambda))\to k[T]$. Suppose that $X$ maps to $f$ and $Y$ maps to $g$, then $g^2=f(f-1)(f-\lambda)$. The ring $k[T]$ is factorial and polynomials $f,f-1,f-\lambda$ have no common irreducible factors, hence they all should be squares. Let $f=a^2$ and $f-1=b^2$, then $1=a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$. So $a-b$ and $a+b$ are constants, hence $f$ and $g$ are constants. So, the morphisms that you want to describe are given by maps of all $\mathbb A^1$ to a point of $E$.

Comment: Great, to keep it fully elementary.

Comment: @danneks  i'm sorry "The ring [] is factorial and polynomials" what is this means?

Comment: @danneks is this means it's a UFD?

Comment: @bolt: yes, I mean that the ring is an UFD and the three polynomials have no common irreducible factors.

Comment: @danneks： oh i got it ! thank you !